# How can I find my global IP address via command prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, router

I'm working with Ubuntu 14. How can I find the global IP address of my router? I know there are lot's of web services, like whatsmyip.org or something, but how can I find it with my command prompt?

Cheers

Comment: Your PC's IP or the Router's IP?

Comment: The web is full of ressources: http://superuser.com/questions/522887/how-can-i-get-my-public-ip-address-from-the-command-line-if-i-am-behind-a-route

Comment: The global IP of the router

Answer (score 0):

found this one here https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip 
and seems pretty simple

wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo

Comment: Thank you. curl ifconfig.me work fine, too. And is easy to remember.

Comment: yep - https://serverfault.com/questions/89114/finding-the-public-ip-address-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score -1):

You can type `ipconfig` in Command Prompt and it will return your IP address.